# System generated approval of document

Tags: docusignapi

Our documents need signature and fiscal approval. We would like the approval to be sent by our procurement system. What's the API call to approve the contract?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking if you can make an API call from your procurement system to "sign".  DocuSign does not have way to apply signatures without a human being taking the action.  You'd need to get the procurement "signature" on the PDF before sending it to DocuSign.  Or you could use a regular text field and do a data merge to fill it in with "electronically approved by Procurement" if that would work.  It would remain your system's responsibility to prove the audit trail of that pseudo signature.